# Grails can't see database table's content

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm using Grails version 2.4.4 and postgresql. When I run app, I see error message `Cannot get property 'myname' on null object`. I know that table is not empty and database connected correctly, because I can upload and see data using scaffolding.

domain class code:

```
class My_table {

     //Integer id
     String myname

     static constraints = {}
}
```

Controller code:

```
class My_tableController {

def index() {
    def my_table = My_table.list()
    [my_table:my_table] 
}
```

My index.gsp file:

```
<g:select name="name" from="${my_table}"/><br/>
    <label>${my_table.myname} </label><br/>
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to call your domain object `Table`? Table is a reserved word in ANSI SQL. Are you sure your table even gets created in Postgres? Can you provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: I gave name table as an example of my real code. Sorry of misunderstood

Comment: please provide the full stacktrace. Your example is misleading.

Comment: This is full struckture. After this code is used I get `500 internal Server Error` with message `Cannot get property 'myname' on null object` and I want to know why

Comment: The question is confusing for at least a couple reasons.  One issue is it looks like `my_table` would be a `List` of instances of `My_table` but in your GSP you are referring to `${my_table.myname}` as if `my_table` was a particular instance.  Is that intentional or are you trying to take advantage of Groovy's special property access on a collection to retrieve `myname` from all of the instances in the `List`?  That doesn't explain why `my_table` is `null`, but clearing that up may contribute to further clarity.

Comment: Mostly I'm using this [tutorial](http://grails.asia/grails-tutorial-for-beginners-display-data-from-the-database)

Comment: That tutorial is doing something different than you show in your example.  I expect the problem is apparent in the parts of the GSP that surround what you showed above.  My guess is you have a `<g:each...` tag that will be relevant.

Comment: Is your project available on Github so I can clone it and take a look at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the form that I see the error happens in this line: `<label>${my_table.myname} </label><br/>`.

Here you are calling the property name out of context

`<g:select name="name" from="${my_table}"/><br/>
    <label>${my_table.myname} </label><br/>`

You get an error because `my_table` is a list of `My_table` instances and does not have a property named name.

A way to fix this problem could be:

```
<select name="name">
    <g:each in="${my_table}" var="table">
        <option value="${table.name}">${table.name}</option>
    </g:each>
</select>
```

Also remember label tags are not valid inside a select, as you can read *Permitted content Zero or more `<option>` or `<optgroup>` elements.* in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Answer (score 0):

Table is a reserved word in most databases. Either change the name of the class and property or map them to something else that is not reserved:

```
static mapping = {
   table 'my_table'
}
```

Adding the column named table to a table named table is problematic because in the static mapping block a method named table already exists. Newer versions of grails have an ORM mapping block that is more flexible.

```
static mapping = {
   table 'my_table'
   table column: 'my_table' // unsure if this would work since it overlaps with the other mapping method
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but my table name  is not 'table', I gave this as example of my code. Sorry of misunderstood